# Microsoft Graph - Users API deltatoken

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We use  Microsoft Graph Users API to track changes of users in Azure AD.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

In API response, we acquire @data.nextlink, to fetch next set of users. This @data.nextlink is unusually long more than 8000 characters for a particular user.  We noticed most of the users contains @data.nextlink,which is less than 4000 characters.

Our Http Client and proxy servers reject the url due to length. Is this an issue? What is the standard length of @data.nextlink.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta?$skiptoken=CWVE8SyYFHfrk4xYFHxyyjsB-BsphNwOPo-vbCJuhNEouCI2oNdgkaSeHwkaUJJ9bZh9Dna67EXCHYh8uOyekYp42dnF4J_h-TYxbruxrMKJeyOxsVYwu63dHFBeYj4IE6XtlOtuADejKHSnPq0vHhvaHWUMnFwvTB3aiMrNQRHV7YhDnqcBAmY4MR32GkZFk9xElNVCvDmql98bwa2QpBU2Vk4RDI07SfKiHCro9jA7zz6HdsMXnBMI_NdKv6boaVdyz29nHTqg7J7G8alLQYlT_88iwppE0JBKpG8SAW_PsTOtrlBeetLYORphdkzm0FZ9lh0v4GrWxb2VGSnuDi-ntJ2qT3TIh8MeJs3xxVxRppK86_RhOoZHcQYK9Py1_0d64_XTdmvBgAPgRy9woIgIpRwYsMLZzsJByNd-OxDXZ-ncfzmezn-bP0vPSGXvo_KTGbpKrboXu3eR_8wvo9gvVDc_scq082DNOAZ_iUCIKwfMeFgminoYlvPK_fRoVdiVEV142TPT9UQCAGsoKRCzsbfTuCB10BbrUdiPKD1uHmKc71M5tmDrF1Bg5nOqvAVzHXUCx6fycvdXzrp_IzO6d99Hxzv1jYfUEmitQfoGjoddtguEQmCdbZiuaSCPRgzt7ykP2na4WuKPK8-Mt_idYh4uWVGsg6TBzfBXK298PCGmk7J1i3w9IfVN2zygoQTMpuxVQb09CT7DzN3iV5cV55ew8XCoZZwLC_Ry17JTcj4c6qfKiAZeTsamp8b9ju41zNqImgodc42fRE6U7nZSSRkWSh8iJImV4uTbMqOZOqf6AlkeMy3KqjaZuGkNIlwAXv4nkfF1vtZkxf-UWp5R-D-c0OBC5vFfYK-MUQkkMlDkTawFCdSpslGfYgCaVKayKKH9RlupHHaJ5G5ts0t1T91J247-V7PGWYwJcAvjUapl3VlOZTOfl2aEvSZYkLPMjX5xbchUwvhkJDqZjZIjH8mUp4znGEK14LqQ-N1MiTDcFWhlmttuKJ0kNNLOno_17GlPpu2mCu0DTkT5ymYmPZzFVIE1BJgP2M2sJFiw1fhMpqObciMpCy5PcMtbUqX54dVcgmnM7z8ZLYX6lMP8aV3xqnVouPiDSihF0RKG7AqjQrWB-wX36w8dREoE7dlinGoXjxg9_ZlG13qR9A0xVyCA7sXJUT03HcnS2KDM1cFlZRW7M5OqIygI_MzrVhjo0K-LgmfCFN2ogNc6LTNZLbPZAaImRnPy3bsYGO_WyYbiG4qkQqo1QKtOwcORnpGOL-ZdPqYzCqsvC_MqtEdxTqFt09jf7tWQPFiEJHMsFOwR2ZiNx8HOyo6TQcj_CmgG2kNownON2sq1sdlqWtm2tzYfDLrG3Vec6oLyB2mAWarqCFsqwvzn6AvWK2y4OpygnMy_eIk2KRrFxRWcnnbrJOeKew7QmNMKzQDfmeLkyA6cln_KTr8mCB6gsL082niZ_ZfY_3yG9sp6RPnN5TF5RxzPFsD1EyvuN6Y9UOme-vinGUJHt-Pc_Hv-rLhAcg-qY0GuA9nOzQDE3vwaJ8deWXxuXkRK1OquJ7h3jkHQU6DnzuBCcJmZWD9yqq-Q_9bKm5nGn_586udpzqjVjRrwOvC5wJOIxvDn3gswfMM99c_9BBVZVEMeB7brrdfNIhl8mLBycZFgfHko72qCMx_d80CD5yqVC8kkMK9uzFbaJuk9-b8PiwlY4zkHlauvjCN7uikrqB8Bf2nlSTPInphyw9iU8aTiN4qhkRRrD0ZTrjWqX8c_OtSlvoJkcZjnDEAQrKVlFmcChzXCA5nRCokyniQ-hPfZjUB9I8K9MyFnrIYYowXCykySUBu-ZFXBFdymHAty7MN-VYkFkzyKh-JvuS3gCJuuyoibmvoVh7f3jvL8kjBcwVWxQne7feriS4SRPqoUzp0iwP5kgW6kbVFf-w0vzwmZTVA8R1Me5BAvgyPM4Cm13TgYYo1TFWBDs062vQfUl7p_iREwMlz_0b84L_UXlmq_A2-cQxsNwFdMHx7gRWk0BWeM96slD6JCOcFXZbxU7WykNW_3UzSe6tUugCMznsIkDvfFeiDGU-WnhnDY9j1zQCdSj6Fft3p2sS51lSHjSRE5SD115dVq7wGcj_GMAOJ5RTRQGpLSnX9_5yJOD7e0QpIEs33XxemBWaucdJIL8kEpVDKhvaNhjut-83uUQ9cdslYIOBKFvRJVZeEZkauEmsb0nnd1QXu_otebvDizo8XQ3hdGNTyGhMgc9pWz3j53VqQN4UVIheViRCH-t6ZxETizymGdMIrMl4jUB2AU0lyqKXtOVYOUKWa0xIA-g64Rxn7TTQA8MMBt-BdGbkffSjCOQAe7EVxtZZSBjwdRFQDNNlZrdIzQapeA6upUHijozNa2e_Z-_8r-NpNzWtg3pYTsC2K4OyV2ldRntLqyTZQUkjdIYr_UwnycerTDWCkDjB2KhIcbxCH6bCtlOBHXCAZdUXoJWrzxjRmYo7vlVUGkicpj_w9JbYq0UfjCuVWStuvmyDcbQ3KlMCxozzpjC1YixQGa7__ZD7lVEUYSIlajGa6SFWvRup_CbhnJ8L3h7kPWU7nG2D6KvNhcablOLC1f_djpBTZD00Z9mRwtsBF3BsmjlbxQS-Deuzph2sMAhMKlGuQCKWs8zGZv-TOMvHnIB2ZAlJEBHq9iOW35xSShBqVx002yMUGwNnmF9__ZtWrG98fFum6myfZP5oBXYPfP5UrtaQvERgCzR6VrDVhEFc0Ix69mWZLp7p41uHCmZx_l4ed_OlPPGkNaldPD29JQj_DgsY6LLUZsCN0EEniVy8wXzLXOte4q3Dqv5WX5JbRGzCmgw6zptCABZTE9m40qPO-Mzg47VjuJK2pepF4_i4zrC_JbHmmxfVgwAVNHD9jw6IPzj81rO5kVlAxNihaTfmof0au6aeMNq5vDQG4_B9rh6bo-6FB95yib5_EmXLnNKwlaJlT0KRhtGhCx0x4bwk0b_8SzPOZ6Kkf3LoCQbSvnO5FKy_ulPIwqF10nZuo6LPVNLxn4B7fpr4kAP2uECVw5mmoAHZw_iIXFiD7AIz99WFXLk8XJ0U1qgqi4287uZXeecaSKXzhjdBbHwr-eF6P48aQibDD91796B_v_1F0pDBxez5buy0WPDtwzHcSVUcUsMc7qRpa-kqGwgkWOzylBXvWbUbBF73Rs9kLrEgkn3VnK7e1ltaHBWuvC8Pnyvdu6HisnrlJTpSRDcNlh6KhV1n-IozOt3MnE3uLwnSK3sWr7HFvPyo-TVicIdZYQAAQ_1bRaYvzskUuv6AheZenqFdPvrqmANntsO_HQnfEY_TqAowecFyggeEDfCxqkz92DL7vMteCZlalzWY-GyXqpdyC6eLneoNz3DlbCDa7eHlvJb1n7-HMbTGr4ItNjrxvoJfzZHqVbv3kbHkZbIULhT-pyvl7bfy1DXP14zEf6Uwa8fDFvWODFCf3OpWim1srKmwTNIIGb9zhAjJha8JaoXznHsrjicCX5AaO0_-NFEepmIGzNvTrTP7VH14E-8gmJezVDlZjgmvrPvhR79E6vAlSGywtYHuskNyJDNhMrDJPOa2g0v3NZYO4PWirK_G5E6xp-oYMMcMaSE7ldjtp9B03Mg5ptkfbZHkbQwUFPNgH79WirPt-U7woJgkS6IMei4VjZbuoFlxvn5V-qYpZ9ZMWEOSpSHhYmIag5fkiMYnuS5WVUqAweHpCP9lHOncYvJzqyiKCZGJcOt94u_E8T3RqCvS-WTLLlm3aIIXw9s4Tt18ivktkxVV3AV03iA4rmRldQK4kk8DrIKPNxIwX4mYNRijoGZRzxpofGA8DRC5XVGFuQxBf4PV1U1DYiAO8BVAiFpTIJRL1WxX70Ei1Q79nA1ZrcNN8TTRbWV2pchhYq29-glbH4AFL_fHq4UrhdzIQDg-SXK8br0sGtphcSWh9wo0vpx9IBHYOPzc6y1kpkqhp1i-V4g0XtHKrXEeoXJLbMjGwRafIpR76SH20LdXTF5kg7W0Ftm4gIJgu9wcLyFr0I43rRZGgQ6htLlj5fVl5C3-OccpDvTzY5_gXDRrJhEqnTol_-thKcDtZ8VIkxaP7p6snBMLXyAfNnFITVR69CjY_wGikFxmUmhC4iTySh5Ie_AbZ9NixpeiVESdw-B_37mVxOQYdZZgR2I0tcWPuZp2tYvCu5W0KcBENPW5FkrrPznU_HoWHu87lVKirpXuS3kQGPHp_74682jsf4kJoTDhwOhacuSCsYsdmz3yFrN-Hjj1QFln99sVQUsJAkGVCb_1-Q0UkDsxuGbaQXJb_wqGErNU6Gtxw1A2CJ5eClzrVmv5fTIWPSenkKXuFI86UcNZQkDa3S1mwGMyHIxZHzbu_CrMbXjhku9WSn3PtCOlu9E_tklN0RlgzS7AqnqP0kTQbjUIbXYorY0uFtZLUXViANEtHFyjO70slUDvUUAbs2ZTmfVtVOPlwCrRhMWU7rxwTHwKGaZUvmItYASrVN_qioe5Nu1p2Hjh55mNGnGgDPfoz1euHczXuvKnqTRtJGVILrWT3IkiKpO0szkxs8qZZEJARPbnx-lNoiIDZg4kv7N34l61siaQfgn6AIeta5I7kCY5jqqz_3TQvikr8bmSF8WyoylD5dEG9jrq35fJpzHEEdw7uMK9kxtrZpbCe4itfKBWpM9W3bMBDGaTFWEDqMWoPZWDnIPWB7dgSziMSV5sh88ehVJqeCvpgmrH7u_rw6Dlh9E_bMno5q3a3Sn4fE8NEDiVQQdbqb6oJEQZ--ndzLrx2dR_nq16Tx7IRZ26yctVpRd_pILk27e7RhpPARbENnQ64zSOSfP3CF537wvxcQkdf7SXotEmXybw8o2w3kVWFizapshPUht8Zaa19_fAV_Cg6YVN19iXO3w8ufodWfaTPZ-7tG0XtBAU6cZTgABTEOWaCAmIqrQSGzXQi7tZSxLks64gG2gfpUMxMMnEX2_-YElW0oekqYxGby1-KksCOFbqtAPhSIo_1Kg4lzap8lWNqczU8kruLLkPep6gPP0aR5OWO4dY1ZaacEtJx9HPDIfPg-UFCHKlyPbcXt7hH82n-6Iy669MRayljdfRsnePP1RVzOepw4nyK5Q7vsYr0Lmu8q4qXuy-Wmy5rGyXOIaXK432Zj_QHdm03used1E1Cl9mgLIXcHOvSvOZnYDga1ruXsCMUFBqv3F8QtzY1jTzvL4nqiLeTvuj_eLZ26qZHdYhDFYbtNOAETfIBgN60lUs1SVsP9EOuIpW-QiqQrVhp76hiW1hHVpBUL73EvU3yRglHaxfeXQuiy0U4qyeWYbcxokig2fjiXFplvityZ74tJuQ1qKV2KpYXtw0mKD62mrG8SNqQSQSl_CSyPg6RRN3ZZaBmi45Z77MoQadD-gX4ld07-M70lJ0mNAQpvGvyZUevQS7cMwHmCpra5VRFo52joVFvDO1mszAukdQJwj6iVHDIJpYrYQVRxsM4Ut-BS4MBbbhKKq2aI4y9BXPP02KzvFNGRO0WwM-ieJYdwpPYK1uqaUgvoWpXJ2gsGHUajCKk4ugIodcYXIxULIlZRAFo5PqhqGxVm415khdauQZrCmQHLiH1WyW3kmXX9Lc4W-D0kYhYaZTxCYQy70DVdRhsxQ81oGjISpsLHDZ-NXhc_xjmfXuFPGP79U1TejfcdAly2Kj-UqkqWiBuU8txgeoblnYYuSlSbBUSRw9pH2PXYq2Pbw8ck-CzpaLZ4dI_HDiFByCc7n_6aq6UYxcd2WlxJQWF1wOfxH67n4cEroSI0S7RuXawhaGBcGbJEGvraoMsxcJGHYjCQx8fCbdXKNsrZUx2l8F3OIQeqoyg9AtXpR3_CDnHbJWlQ9LpWlZ856C8arqrKnE1PrVcr3CivAj_pg2KhyXzRgazYvrMGs6NpLOtvzMfnGZ7eo1I1ZP20645me9qdsstkd-EVhFdUZNZaqKEOcu_7tL-Da0zFkitS-Zj2Iw291QyRRtlscPfL-9V--EqtCDFKALbuwQqvmwLLdTdjs7glWn9tp6mEr1h4h4YVAvyDBGUNyetDgATczmpTgHJfpWm5cG8s2SX9UhN3ZEJ1h9Ns5X5kN4WOlcri85Ek5oKyP-f9mQ7G4J4jYVyzA47klHgIezKuslxKLwNj67x0MuQ4EaZwWDPnYd7g5689CXxr-0bnZPMceO562tTEv1d-tW84zRCuv3mAVVKKJ8Q1J9-E9UVHmivduXtHA6P5uO1-rUiuxdOaR5ujVIPn0Fl_0Dte79ca2uKE5fHU6D5k6lsa7vG3eI9JQljVknF6DTDYdMx71b_ZS4GM4JQivGYLzgEVB7yOGZYKNxuZkNpeyqEI8WbepTerk9kKv0tnrQ_tNg3YhFQQ1ALO8jOWm3G2rSgv0N6RX3BCD7IPSVX5JgYWW6hsdepU06fQ3Bm-XoJ8U2D1kgDXRXzxraj75rSSWn6ec9iQaeiOfpM4PddOR9htMY_zY6TGqUTANSwwBXIdF3Aw1vsViVZjAN0d6mna5ByXJNw1gDAuF2yxA7fjEljOqLHgaWLv4ZlEsNUg1YARVDOs9-GwzQxtXNCUBT8311j0sKPr22DmwAzE4U-WClesOwl0iFco42LkCIdhOhy0ZYzLWZZpE9GhDcRF5iBmU0HobwX18ehkd9COcm6BCPt_0_90dLyWptAtaheaRTbvajE983iEch1WNje84T3XaEeM2jVsD22539jyUhuqgVhe7W1TCV6bzxF-6NsQyYi_C6R0vipJyQmlntel0bzoSvO0pQGLFO3p6riSU1-HsMh7BwXub6QMUuYdylSdNItpgg4vX2Zz14pquxbeamHcHaYcDTT81RYifMd_O8Fqdb81bo1g6emAV5GrRrlhZf8JTjM9rPbwR544I7dqeTcVuo434HGE4Dov_yaMwaaf-DyluikpJBZzRFMcaKIEUFdqBpJnR58vNhDF__f_9dtp9WeG2Swb6ps-triONtMcqlPw8cTh_u4O9BCHW3zzNRhyvNHZgEcDz0r9c9T1Bsgfcvi9eK1Xtad7sfXnACMiYNI2hk_8aB3p2O1yzzlWqJbMixcdjDinJa_3h1RItXC5-grF0dhRPK2N9vrwWb7WeXkzVHH36cHGRFdVsinWUiYp0E01e0SPnyqdHG25n4gBG7jbcTs2ga9qpzF-2zzbIGF3bh84GWvNqyc3MOlra5xAmcRYVZwWELMK4qHCIckM0cVhMEsb8A1fBzUu2BxypeOqky78fA7cwhGVZ4qEUvg72HoMT93TqDzrc4mlVOVmWnacptpfWS7YgxqArLBMHxVAT4n_jJ3rnwiBYsn68FATCHErJxncEjgO-NIJVXLG_cGoSGqN5RD2FrJYvnwJNdOZBeLU9TjOYf9oPviUzN7bpZI1oNlS-16woIqEJe86cHzDG650KkPadxxifd_60I2w0jDlmV77woy6wOpHR2NR1e6rVWI2edWkYeVTlX2hi_9CE5SwlRycVm3CZebCGA0nH-V8-cPywLOfr_9Wr7McXuVmTBAVMRlyP5L0Tea_Js598dUAaz1SbYsZbDlTEzDz8adyw6RBpU-F-FfK9d6LZeVOoWfas8ZbB4fJJIr1MiuyzZYtZsA-QK2HJ0XjkuGIdbYmx-XgeJrgqWoSKhcEbqW7NaavHPbOZgqPujp_D2v6Jdb8U0KPm9yY-fkW2lmYHuUI3qQYu0gCClC5D_ph1GOF0KwADPTyqiwt0QjqdXIitsmEWg28tBYM340BZb_aAPZPB01ddqlUJyYs2xFtK6Lq14dMqRZMEYumZIRKQ97OyTYA3CfzRbXKSiEZc_gN4ZaSqZSG6-Rdx8_7G2DeJVwRnJ6yE6gTF7eTyCcubCFNmiCQHxEqrig6jhK4Hl4BUUFqMeciBkLWLKbzQ1WUR0A5BR8u2_TnNalMI3oIwmy2T6i3h678oFYFKtu0fPLls1yXb_3YezxeBmMZwdMcxYe4HJ2YJBDD7NfIO6YEgCUCspliEJyZmDbdzjB3lAGmJhgAYKLP7R45WLR6SVtm9BProbOxsVAZynG4T5r3VGApQSHyVCMFAKlZ5CtyCxhwfY_IiN6-ouWrcxN9is_SCYw0zv7tVDHtLK895frQ3HmiZoXIkF8kTi4Dsbg58LzM979LA335xFfrmtEz35Qk67XZt_hq4cAOfybpdHdXJmCg2s0_rTIrKt6cvJhOEYdvPxqFQKfFrDR-SENi8PEw5OSqvADVxGS_QRNHIXXnEOgmKV9Kz0lM6I49L-JwMNj-2seUcKQOpp5eJs7NCoXyUclxqItUwoKgTjMrEgs7wtEzGwKbLWKOQ5uRnMbnkbn_jPmGeZJGB8xWPptekL1VatYX37PfYYOFW5trLr8tZHjmNDYjWUUKfiqwLDJJ3QG6GQ_NaiEhtPWNe4XAfDH3w2ByIOm9iLK51l2ItiSz1PYVI6or26DBTkzrj9CveFJ3ZMcz3y1eVT6yNmbTK9mt.DNpsG3CyCU3fAACL7LysDb0Mq1eED3D-LiBTlwl_CT0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delta links cannot exceed 16 000 characters.
The suggestion is to update your code/configuration/infrastructure so it can support URLs up to 16k characters.
If you can't upgrade your infrastructure to support such length, you could wrap the request into a [batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching) to overcome that limitation (the delta link will be in the body and not the request URL anymore)

Comment: I cannot find any source for this, would you mind sharing yours?

Comment: I was the program manager for the feature when I replied and asked directly to the engineering group.